# Each ggplot on separate pdf page - plot row by row

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to put one line plot on each page of pdf file. All the data for plotting is stored in single data frame. Each row should be plotted.

That's how the data looks like:

```
structure(list(`10` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `34` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 370500, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1091361.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1512409.6, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `59` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4231358.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5995680.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2266775, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6864490.1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), `84` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1783350, 0, 0, 0, 1177650, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4316664.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9262556.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2831286.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10643218.2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `110` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1778743.3, 0, 0, 0, 
1465966.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3111700, 0, 0, 1955337.5, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5584784.4, 5584784.4, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3092525, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7847143.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `134` = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 1121869.4, 0, 0, 0, 1439430.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
2854250, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 914890, 0, 0, 847880, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 8191800, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1830904.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1650150, 0, 0, 837130, 0, 0, 0, 4925095.1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `165` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1432775, 0, 0, 0, 1394186.1, 
0, 1120183.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2262421.7, 0, 0, 0, 615660, 0, 
0, 1292795.8, 0, 0, 712622.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2683469.4, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2318485.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1561800, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4382993.7, 0, 0, 763460, 0, 0, 0), `199` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 1314220, 0, 0, 0, 1439718.8, 0, 1929266.7, 0, 0, 0, 
1101800, 0, 0, 2759366.7, 0, 0, 0, 1291728.6, 0, 0, 2489775.6, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2858345.8, 0, 0, 0, 1819542.1, 
0, 0, 1497640.3, 0, 0, 0, 1300250, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1566875, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4625895.6, 0, 0, 1308158.3, 0, 0, 0), `234` = c(1257250, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1276080, 0, 1848500, 0, 0, 0, 1529350, 0, 
0, 2155275, 0, 0, 0, 2023041.9, 0, 0, 1966447.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1184200, 1184200, 0, 0, 1652350, 0, 0, 2018581.7, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1835225, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4639414.7, 
0, 0, 720715, 0, 0, 0), `257` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 669442.5, 0, 
0, 1253026.7, 0, 960410, 960410, 0, 0, 1258267.5, 0, 0, 1707392.5, 
0, 0, 0, 563280, 0, 0, 2403237.9, 0, 0, 0, 1044100, 0, 2075700, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5718450, 0, 0, 1704550, 0, 0, 1350286.9, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 2011700, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1739500, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4612520.8, 
4612520.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `362` = c(0, 1593500, 0, 0, 0, 1610625.3, 
0, 0, 1234902.5, 0, 0, 1481036.8, 0, 0, 1583647.5, 0, 0, 1752089.2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2410809.2, 0, 0, 0, 654940, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 7014905.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1165672.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1029910, 0, 0, 2153087.5, 0, 0, 0, 422920, 0, 0, 0, 7495855.9, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `433` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1340283.9, 0, 0, 1268996.9, 
0, 0, 1416683.3, 0, 0, 1047862.5, 0, 0, 1819653.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 2227565.7, 0, 0, 0, 763765, 0, 0, 1595430, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
4894549, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1061375.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2251950, 0, 
1042130, 0, 0, 2055300, 0, 0, 0, 696278.3, 0, 0, 0, 5353797.8, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `506` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2020300, 
2020300, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7681526, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `581` = c(0, 
0, 1749237.5, 0, 0, 0, 2421665.8, 0, 0, 1773262.5, 0, 0, 2251004.3, 
0, 0, 2570175, 0, 0, 3379756.9, 0, 0, 0, 2054455.6, 0, 0, 2518270.8, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2917968.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7004350, 0, 0, 1451600, 
0, 0, 1394411, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2507858.3, 0, 2377012.5, 0, 0, 
3719165.4, 0, 0, 0, 1472870.3, 0, 0, 9666916.1, 0, 0, 1730300, 
0, 0), `652` = c(0, 0, 476910, 476910, 0, 0, 1149078.8, 1149078.8, 
0, 1082468.7, 0, 0, 882769.7, 0, 0, 1370449.4, 1370449.4, 0, 
1529049, 1529049, 0, 0, 943632.2, 0, 0, 916587.8, 0, 0, 0, 988261.1, 
0, 0, 1778007.1, 1778007.1, 0, 0, 0, 3087304.8, 3087304.8, 0, 
782860, 782860, 0, 510158.5, 510158.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1503750, 0, 
1100677.5, 1100677.5, 0, 1669260, 1669260, 0, 0, 770733.2, 0, 
0, 4939242.8, 4939242.8, 0, 643564.4, 643564.4, 0), `733` = c(0, 
0, 0, 1095060, 0, 0, 0, 1674089.3, 0, 1252101.3, 0, 0, 1259111, 
0, 0, 0, 2429293.3, 0, 0, 2326928.3, 0, 0, 1259216.5, 0, 0, 1238837.5, 
0, 0, 0, 1224858.3, 0, 0, 0, 2952529.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4626414.7, 
0, 0, 1121440, 0, 0, 1025386.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1917900, 0, 0, 2197533.3, 
0, 0, 2840155.5, 0, 0, 1054285.7, 0, 0, 0, 7516814.2, 0, 0, 1329434.4, 
0), `818` = c(0, 0, 0, 720551.1, 0, 0, 0, 714662.7, 0, 617012.9, 
0, 0, 549850.8, 0, 0, 0, 1197460, 0, 0, 771979.2, 0, 0, 585847.5, 
585847.5, 0, 875475.4, 0, 0, 0, 576774, 0, 0, 0, 1147389.8, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 2292421.7, 0, 0, 755258.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 858930, 
0, 0, 1242668.3, 0, 0, 1580088.3, 0, 0, 641938.6, 641938.6, 0, 
0, 3838660.4, 0, 0, 733140.8, 733140.8), `896` = c(0, 0, 0, 590480, 
0, 0, 0, 817087.6, 0, 569869.5, 0, 0, 650822.5, 650822.5, 0, 
0, 1624052.5, 0, 0, 682570.8, 0, 0, 0, 1538800, 0, 690488.6, 
690488.6, 0, 0, 797923.9, 0, 0, 0, 1204889.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2184432.2, 
0, 0, 676654.7, 0, 0, 0, 210680, 0, 0, 0, 791152.5, 0, 0, 1599855.8, 
0, 0, 1358543.8, 0, 0, 0, 931288, 0, 0, 4683895.2, 0, 0, 0, 1202806
), `972` = c(0, 0, 0, 799116.4, 0, 0, 0, 759169.9, 0, 408845, 
0, 0, 0, 948980, 0, 0, 968766.7, 0, 0, 675349.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1811117.6, 0, 0, 609098.5, 0, 0, 0, 1073749.1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 2392258.9, 0, 0, 743580, 0, 0, 0, 1020485, 0, 0, 0, 446596.7, 
0, 0, 1178583, 0, 0, 1438261.7, 0, 0, 0, 1133057.9, 0, 0, 4445814.7, 
0, 0, 0, 1057776.9), `1039` = c(0, 0, 0, 447255.3, 0, 0, 0, 609409.1, 
0, 304340, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 694232.8, 0, 0, 473015.3, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 419524.9, 0, 0, 447760.6, 0, 0, 0, 932513.5, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1251960.5, 0, 0, 276560, 0, 0, 0, 259640, 0, 0, 0, 354995, 
0, 0, 1570222.5, 0, 0, 1021822, 0, 0, 0, 811614, 0, 0, 2941698.2, 
0, 0, 0, 1199942.5), Gene = 1:67), .Names = c("10", "34", "59", 
"84", "110", "134", "165", "199", "234", "257", "362", "433", 
"506", "581", "652", "733", "818", "896", "972", "1039", "Gene"
), row.names = c(NA, 67L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have tried something like that so far...:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(Tra_decon)){

  Tra_decon_melt <- melt(Tra_decon[i,], id = "Gene")

  pdf("Test_plot.pdf", onefile = TRUE)
  ggplot(Tra_decon_melt, aes(variable, log10(value), group=factor(Gene))) +
    theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
    ylab("XXX") +
    xlab("XXX") +
    geom_line(aes(color=factor(Gene)), size = 1.2) +
    ggtitle("XXXX") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
  dev.off()

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution without a for loop (and so faster) is this one:

```
plots <-  lapply(1:nrow(Tra_decon), function(i){
  Tra_decon_melt <- melt(Tra_decon[i,], id = "Gene")

  ggplot(Tra_decon_melt, aes(variable, log10(value), group=factor(Gene))) +
    theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
    ylab("XXX") +
    xlab("XXX") +
    geom_line(aes(color=factor(Gene)), size = 1.2) +
    ggtitle("XXXX") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))

})

pdf("Test_plot.pdf", onefile = TRUE)
plots
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
   pdf("Test_plot.pdf", onefile = TRUE)
    for(i in 1:nrow(Tra_decon)){

      Tra_decon_melt <- melt(Tra_decon[i,], id.vars = "Gene")

      plot<-list()
      plot[[i]]<-ggplot(Tra_decon_melt, aes(variable, log10(value), group=factor(Gene))) +
        theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
        ylab("XXX") +
        xlab("XXX") +
        geom_line(aes(color=factor(Gene)), size = 1.2) +
        ggtitle("XXXX") +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
      print(plot[[i]])

    }
    dev.off()
```